# C# Best method to create unique int32 identifier for complex object

Tags: c#, hash, uid

I have a problem with getting unique int32 identifier with this properties:

- It has to be always the same for the same objects in current instance of a program
- It has to always differ in current instance of a program for different objects, so no collisions at all.

I need that unique identifier for comparing complex objects and working with classes like Dictionary<> or HashSet<> etc.

I would very much like to avoid using any kind of hash tables or precalculations of any kind but instead to have an algorithm that will do that on the fly in order to exclude external dependencies and make unit testing easier

Pseudocode of an object:

```
    class ComplexObject
    {
        public readonly FirstEnum First; // ~50 different values
        public readonly IFirstModificator FirstModificator; // 4 implementations x 15 values (~60 values total)
        public readonly InternalObject[] Internal; //1-10 values in array 
    }

    class InternalObject
    {
        public readonly SecondEnum Second; // ~30 different values
        public readonly SecondModificator SecondModificator; //  ~15 different values
    }
```

In  case its important my domain model contains about 100 000 unique objects of type ComplexObject

I already tried:

- Serializing an object into json and getting a hash of that string(by using string.GetHashCode() method). It produces collisions even in current instance of a program.
- Code like this produces  a lot of collisions too:

```
    unchecked
    {
        int hash = 17;
        hash = hash * 31 + firstField.GetHashCode();
        hash = hash * 31 + secondField.GetHashCode();
        return hash;
    }

    unchecked 
    {
        int hash = (int) 17;
        hash = (hash * 31) ^ field1.GetHashCode();
        hash = (hash * 31) ^ field2.GetHashCode();
        return hash;
    }
```

**UPDATED:**

IFirstModificator has different implementations, but in general it looks like that:

```
    class FirstModificator : IFirstModificator
    {
        public int Value {get;set;} //~15 values
    }
```

Other parameters of implementation IFirstModificator affect \ apply to (not sure if my English is clear) only data processing.

```
    class SecondModificator 
    {
        public int Value {get;set;} //~15 values
    }
```

External interface and data requred for creating instance of a class are similar to implementation IFirstModificator but they are in fact different classes.

Comment: An `Int32` has a mere 32 bits to play with and that's [simply not enough](https://preshing.com/20110504/hash-collision-probabilities/) to guarantee collision-free hashing for that many objects (assuming you cannot use any special properties of value distribution). Note however that collision-free hashing is *not required* to correctly use classes like `Dictionary`; a collision just means performance will be a bit less since multiple objects will occupy the same bucket. Searching a list for 2 or 3 objects that collided is not *much* slower than just fetching one.

Comment: If your remarks on the number of different values is accurate, it would seem you do not actually have more than 2^31 unique *possible* objects, meaning that you can definitely produce a hash that hashes unique objects uniquely. This involves essentially assigning a unique number to every combination, so tailor it to your distribution (i.e. hash `InternalObject` by mapping all `SecondModificator` values to 0-15 and `Second` to 0-30, then do `SecondModificator * 16 + Second`). Of course this can be much harder than just a generic hash.

Comment: Note that in the case of your equality comparison being very slow and that being the bottleneck on collisions (which might be the case with very large objects) you can speed things up by calculating a second, bigger hash (even an `Int64` would be enough), storing that with your object (or a separate `ConditionalWeakTable`) and checking that for a match before doing the full equality comparison. However, your objects don't appear to be large enough to warrant this, taking up at most a few bytes. Collisions would have to get very bad before that's really an issue.

Comment: Can you provide some details on `IFirstModificator` and `SecondModificator` and their implementations? Also what constitutes identity for an object? Is it possible to have duplicate `InternalObject` objects or duplicate `ComplexObject` objects that must be treated as different?

Comment: @jeroen-mostert Thanks for your advice. In this case its crucial that different (not equal by important for domain model parameters) objects wont be placed into the same bucket for multiple reasons but in case of collisions that happens sometimes.

Comment: @netmage i updated main post to answer your questions.

Comment: Is it possible to have duplicate InternalObject objects or duplicate ComplexObject objects that must be treated as different? By duplicate I mean objects with the same field values that must be treated differently for `HashCode` purposes.

Comment: @netmage no, it is impossible. Any objects with same field values are equal by this identificator value (hash).

Comment: Does the order of members of the `InternalObject` array matter? Should the hashcode reflect if they are in a different order in two `ComplexObject`s?

Answer (score 1):

So this is a sample implementation of @JeroenMostert was suggesting.

First, you can create an `InternalObject` hashcode based on the possible values of the differing fields:

```
class InternalObject { // ~450 different values
    public readonly SecondEnum Second; // ~30 different values
    public readonly SecondModificator SecondModificator; //  ~15 different values

    public override int GetHashCode() {
        var hc = (int)Second; // use 5 bits
        // assume SecondModificator.Value values range from 0 - 15 or can be normalized
        hc = hc << 5 + SecondModificator.Value;
        return hc;
    }
}
```

Then you can create a hashcode for the `ComplexObject` based on the possible values of each field there. This hashcode implementation assumes all the `IFirstModificator.Value` fields will range from 0 - 15 and that you don't want to add a new `int` field to `IFirstModificator` representing which implementation is stored in `ComplexObject`, so instead I use Reflection to map the actual implementation type to an `int` from 1 - 4.
If any of the `Value` properties are not a simple range from 0 - 15 you must normalize them to that range using their known possible values.

```
class ComplexObject {
    public readonly FirstEnum First; // ~50 different values
    public readonly IFirstModificator FirstModificator; // 4 implementations x 15 values (~60 values total)
    public readonly InternalObject[] Internal; //1-10 values in array => ~4500 different values

    static Dictionary<Type, int> FirstModMap = new[] { typeof(FirstModificator1), typeof(FirstModificator2), typeof(FirstModificator3), typeof(FirstModificator4) }
                                                .Select((t, n) => new { t, n })
                                                .ToDictionary(tn => tn.t, tn => tn.n + 1);
    public override int GetHashCode() {
        var hc = (int)First; // use 6 bits
        // assume IFirstModificator.Value values are 0 - 14 or normalize to be so
        hc = hc << 6 + (FirstModificator.Value * FirstModMap[FirstModificator.GetType()]); // uses 6 bits
        // assume InternalObject[] order matters
        hc = hc << 12 + Internal.Select((io, n) => io.GetHashCode() * (n + 1)).Sum(); // uses 13 bits

        return hc;
    }
}
```